# Why does Scala type inference fail in one case but not the other?

Tags: scala, type-inference

**Background:** I'm using `net.liftweb.record` with MongoDB to access a database. At some point, I was in need of drawing a table of a collection of documents from the database (and render them as an ASCII table). I ran into very obscure type inference issues which are very easy to solve but nevertheless made me want to understand why they were happening.

**Reproduction:** For simplicity, I've reduced the code to (what I think is) an absolute minimum, so that it only depends on `net.liftweb.record` and none of the Mongo specific types. I've kept the real-life body of the function under question to make the example more realistic.

`makeTable` takes some apples, and some functions that map apples to columns. Columns can either be mapped to a real field on the apples, or a dynamically computed value (with a name). To be able to mix the two (real fields and dynamic values) in a single `Seq`, I defined a structural type `Col`.

To see how the code (below) behaves, try the following variants of the `cols` parameter to `makeTable`:

```scala
// OK:
cols = Seq(_.isDone)
cols = Seq(job => dynCol1)
cols = Seq(job => dynCol1, job => dynCol2)

// ERROR: found: Seq[Job => Object], required: Seq[Job => Test.Col]
cols = Seq(_.isDone, job => dynCol1)
cols = Seq(_.isDone, job => dynCol2)
cols = Seq(_.isDone, job => dynCol1, job => dynCol2)
```

...so whenever `_.isDone` (i.e. the column that maps to a physical field) is mixed with any other "flavor" of column, the error occurs (**CASE 1**). Alone it behaves well; other flavors of column also behave well when alone or mixed (**CASE 2**).

**Intuitive workaround:** marking `cols` as `Seq[Job => Col]` ALWAYS fixes the error.

**Counter-intuitive workaround:** explicitly marking *any* of the return values of the functions in the `Seq` as `Col`, or any of the functions as `Job => Col`, solves the issue.

---

The code:

```scala
import net.liftweb.record.{ Record, MetaRecord }
import net.liftweb.record.field.IntField
import scala.language.reflectiveCalls

class Job extends Record[Job] {
  def meta = Job
  object isDone extends IntField(this)
}
object Job extends Job with MetaRecord[Job]

object Test extends App {
  type Col = { def name: String; def get: Any }

  def makeTable[T](xs: Seq[T])(cols: Seq[T => Col]) = {
    assert(xs.size >= 1)
    val rows = xs map { x => cols { map { _(x).get } }
    val header = cols map { _(xs.head).name }
    (header +: rows)
  }

  val dynCol1 = new { def name = "dyncol1"; def get = "dyn1" }
  val dynCol2 = new { def name = "dyncol2"; def get = "dyn2" }

  val jobs = Seq(Job.createRecord, Job.createRecord)
  makeTable(jobs)(Seq(
    _.isDone,
    job => dynCol1,
    job => dynCol2
  ))
}
```

**P.S.** I'm not adding a lift or lift-record tag because I think this is not related to Lift and is simply a Scala question triggered by what happens to be a Lift-specific situation. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm curious to know what happens if you replace the `def meta = Job` with `def meta = this.type`

Comment: @Michael Meta points to the `Job` singleton object, not to the type. Erik, what are you trying to achieve? It looks like a big code smell.

Comment: @flavian: I thought I described what I was after: it's basically for dumping parts of DB documents as ASCII-formatted tables (I skipped that part and only kept the `Seq[Seq[Any]]` building part). The implementation was supposed to be a quick way to go about it, until I got curious as to why my `Col` structural type wasn't behaving as I intended (and why it was behaving well with simple dummy types).

Comment: @flavian: basically I could have reproduced the issue with a totally meaningless example but I wanted to keep it meaningful for the purpose of intuitiveness. I also tried to reproduce the issue without any Lift Record involved, but the issue only seems to occur when `Field` is involved. So the question is simply: why does (structural) type inference fail when `Field` is mixed with others in the same `Seq`.

Comment: @flavian: again, I could have just avoided `Col` altogether and used functions that always return concrete name-value pairs, but that's not the point here—as I said, the issue is easy to solve (in various ways) but I got curious.